# Laravel 5 Composer Require laravelcollective/html Error

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, laravelcollective

When I was going to require `laravelcollective/html`, there is something wrong! I searched this error in Google but didn't find any answer. Any help?
 Thanks a lot!

```
D:\wamp\www\laravel-5.1>composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.1.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing laravel/framework (v5.1.19)
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.1.19)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing laravelcollective/html (v5.1.6)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::refreshNameLookups()

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:
```

Comment: Try deleting `storage/framework/compiled.php` and rerunning it

Comment: There might also be one in `vendor/compiled.php`

Comment: You should do composer require laravelcollective/html